# Incoming MediaStream's using Safari on mobile device won't play

Tags: safari, webkit, web-audio-api, mediastream

I've been trying to debug this issue, I'm creating a peer to peer audio streaming app.

Each time a mobile device using Safari receives a peers incoming MediaStream, it plays the stream for a fraction of a second and then stops.

I've checked the actual MediaStream & Audio object I'm using to play the incoming stream, but nothing of its status suggests that's it's paused, inactive or stopped.

I know there are some issues with Safari when it comes to programmatically playing Audio, but I thought that was on the initial playback of the clients first stream and then all subsequent streams should work.

I used the implementation from this [article](https://arrangeactassert.com/posts/how-to-fix-the-request-is-not-allowed-by-the-user-agent-or-the-platform-in-the-current-context-possibly-because-the-user-denied-permission/).

Anyone know of the reason for this?